# What is the opposite of process?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is another word for the opposite of process?

I am thinking of something along the lines of "end result." I am trying to say "... the [insert word i am looking for] of the imagination."

Comment: The opposite of process is disorder.

Comment: In law, the opposite of [due] process is arbitrary action. But as often happens at EL&U with requests for opposites, you may be asking not for the opposite (or negative) of _process_, but the logical counterpart of _process_, which I would say is _outcome_.

Answer (score 1):

**... the** [product] **of the imagination"**

second meaning in [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/product) for **product**

> something that is the result of a process

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch your wording around a bit, but either way ...

**The imagination culminates in**

or **The culmination of the imagination**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, **"the expression of imagination"** could fit. 
You could also try **"a work of imagination"**.

In artistic context, we wouldn't talk about "products", we'd talks about "works of art", "artistic expression", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, *the **fruit** of the imagination.* [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fruit+of+his+imagination%2Cfruit+of+our+imagination%2Cfruit+of+my+imagination%2Cfruit+of+their+imagination&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfruit%20of%20his%20imagination%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfruit%20of%20our%20imagination%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfruit%20of%20my%20imagination%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfruit%20of%20their%20imagination%3B%2Cc0)

> fruit: the effect or consequence of an action or operation :  product, result : *the fruits of our labor* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fruit)